# Nginx rate limiting not working as expected based on client IP, instead it works for global IPs

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy, rate-limiting

I want to set rate limit for a specific API request per client IP basis.

I have the nginx configuration to rate limit a specific API /testAPI - each client not to exceed more than 10r/m

```
# these config lines are included on http block
limit_req_zone $binary_remote_addr zone=rl:10m rate=10r/m;
limit_conn_dry_run off;
limit_req_dry_run off;
limit_conn_log_level error;
limit_req_log_level error;
limit_req_status 444;
limit_conn_status 503;
```

On the location block added the rl to take extra 7 request on burst.

```
location ~ ^/testAPI {
      limit_req zone=rl burst=7 nodelay;
      ...
}
```

error logs:

```
2022/11/29 16:04:52 [error] 267#267: *1455 limiting requests, excess: 7.069 by zone "rl", client: 10.78.95.189, server: hulk-reverseproxy.company.com, request: "GET /testAPI HTTP/1.1", host: "hulk-reverseproxy125.company.com:8445"
2022/11/29 16:04:53 [error] 267#267: *1455 limiting requests, excess: 7.048 by zone "rl", client: 10.78.95.189, server: hulk-reverseproxy.company.com, request: "GET /testAPI HTTP/1.1", host: "hulk-reverseproxy125.company.com:8445"
2022/11/29 16:04:53 [error] 267#267: *1455 limiting requests, excess: 7.028 by zone "rl", client: 10.78.95.189, server: hulk-reverseproxy.company.com, request: "GET /testAPI HTTP/1.1", host: "hulk-reverseproxy125.company.com:8445"
2022/11/29 16:04:56 [error] 268#268: *1457 limiting requests, excess: 7.400 by zone "rl", client: 10.65.78.46, server: hulk-reverseproxy.company.com, request: "GET /testAPI HTTP/1.1", host: "hulk-reverseproxy125.company.com:8445"
2022/11/29 16:04:58 [error] 268#268: *1457 limiting requests, excess: 7.220 by zone "rl", client: 10.65.78.46, server: hulk-reverseproxy.company.com, request: "GET /testAPI HTTP/1.1", host: "hulk-reverseproxy125.company.com:8445"
2022/11/29 16:04:59 [error] 268#268: *1457 limiting requests, excess: 7.053 by zone "rl", client: 10.65.78.46, server: hulk-reverseproxy.company.com, request: "GET /testAPI HTTP/1.1", host: "hulk-reverseproxy125.company:8445"
```

I did push multiple requests from IP 10.78.95.189 and ngnix started rejecting request.
As expected the burst requests are rejected from 10.78.95.189.

And I sent only 1 request from 10.65.78.46 at the same time when the above limits are reached, this single request also being rejected, my expectation was requests from 10.65.78.46 should take first 10 requests on first minute without any issue.

Note: Here, Im directly hitting the nginx without any Loadbalancer or CDN.

Also, the rejected requests returned with 403 error code, but I set reject code as 444.

Did I miss something here?

Answer (score -2):

I was doing random changes on the configs and reloading the nginx config instead of nginx restart.
These config changes requires nginx restart. If fixed my issue.

Comment: I have the same problem and a restart doesn't solve it. Did you do anything else to make this work?